# php remove duplicate words in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for English is not my mother language, maybe the question title is not quite good. I want to do something like this.

```
$str = array("Lincoln Crown","Crown Court","go holiday","house fire","John Hinton","Hinton Jailed");
```

here is an array,  "Lincoln Crown" contain "Lincoln" and "Crown", so remove next words, which contains these 2 words, and "Crown Court(contain Crown)" has been removed.

in another case. "John Hinton" contain "John" and "Hinton", so "Hinton Jailed(contain Hinton)" has been removed. the final output should be like this:

```
$output = array("Lincoln Crown","go holiday","house fire","John Hinton");
```

for my php skill is not good, it is not simply to use array_unique() array_diff(), so open a question for help, thanks.

Comment: Aside your problem, What about "Courtney Cox" and "Cox Cable" - totally different application of the word Cox. If this is for something where this scenario is applicable you may not want to just exclude based on the presence of one word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work :P

```
function cool_function($strs){
    // Black list
    $toExclude = array();

    foreach($strs as $s){
        // If it's not on blacklist, then search for it
        if(!in_array($s, $toExclude)){
            // Explode into blocks
            foreach(explode(" ",$s) as $block){
                // Search the block on array
                $found = preg_grep("/" . preg_quote($block) . "/", $strs);
                foreach($found as $k => $f){
                    if($f != $s){
                        // Place each found item that's different from current item into blacklist
                        $toExclude[$k] = $f;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Unset all keys that was found
    foreach($toExclude as $k => $v){
        unset($strs[$k]);
    }

    // Return the result
    return $strs;
}

$strs = array("Lincoln Crown","Crown Court","go holiday","house fire","John Hinton","Hinton Jailed");
print_r(cool_function($strs));
```

Dump:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lincoln Crown
    [2] => go holiday
    [3] => house fire
    [4] => John Hinton
)
```

Comment: +1 I am still trying to make my own version of this, and failing :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you would need a loop and then build a list of words in the array.

Like:

```
<?
// Store existing array's words; elements will compare their words to this array
// if an element's words are already in this array, the element is deleted
// else the element has its words added to this array
$arrayWords = array();

// Loop through your existing array of elements
foreach ($existingArray as $key => $phrase) {
    // Get element's individual words
    $words = explode(" ", $phrase);

    // Assume the element will not be deleted
    $keepWords = true;

    // Loop through the element's words
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        // If one of the words is already in arrayWords (another element uses the word)
        if (in_array($word, $arrayWords)) {
            // Delete the element
            unset($existingArray[$key]);

            // Indicate we are not keeping any of the element's words
            $keepWords = false;

            // Stop the foreach loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // Only add the element's words to arrayWords if the entire element stays
    if ($keepWords) {
        $arrayWords = array_merge($arrayWords, $words);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I would do in your case:

```
$words = array();

foreach($str as $key =>$entry)
{
   $entryWords = explode(' ', $entry);
   $isDuplicated = false;
   foreach($entryWords as $word)
        if(in_array($word, $words))
            $isDuplicated = true;
   if(!$isDuplicated)
        $words = array_merge($words, $entryWords);
   else
        unset($str[$key]);
}

var_dump($str);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Lincoln Crown' (length=13)
  2 => string 'go holiday' (length=10)
  3 => string 'house fire' (length=10)
  4 => string 'John Hinton' (length=11)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine quite a few techniques that can provide your desired output, but the logic that you require is poorly defined in your question.  I am assuming that whole word matching is required -- so word boundaries should be used in any regex patterns.  Case sensitivity isn't mentioned. I am unsure if only fully unique elements (multi-word strings) should have their words entered into the black list.  I'll offer a few snippets, but choosing the appropriate technique will depend on exact logical requirements.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4Aplt)

```
$output = [];
$blacklist = [];
foreach ($input as $string) {
    if (!$blacklist || !preg_match('/\b(?:' . implode('|', $blacklist) . ')\b/', $string)) {
        $output[] = $string;
    }
    foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $word) {
        $blacklist[$word] = preg_quote($word);
    }
}
var_export($output);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8rQ33)

```
$output = [];
$blacklist = [];
foreach ($input as $string) {
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (in_array($word, $blacklist)) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    array_push($blacklist, ...$words);
    $output[] = $string;
}
var_export($output);
```

### And my favorite because it performs fewest iterations in the parent loop, is more compact, and doesn't require the declaration/maintenance of a blacklist array.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/iZQkt)

```
$output = [];
while ($input) {
    $output[] = $words = array_shift($input);
    $input = preg_grep('~\b(?:\Q' . str_replace(' ', '\E|\Q', $words) . '\E)\b~', $input, PREG_GREP_INVERT); 
}
var_export($output);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) each string in the original array and then compare per-words using a loop (comparing each word from one array with each word from another, and if they match, remove the whole array).

Answer (score -1):

**array_unique()** example

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)